# How to clear Cookies,Cache,Passwords individually in IE?

Tags: 8.0, internet-explorer

Does anyone know how to clear cookies , caches,forms individually in IE on Windows 8 Phone?

Answer (score 1):

They can only be cleared together at the moment by going into the Internet Explorer settings, and using the <kbd>delete history</kbd> button